# How to determine whether dynamical systems are dissipative, conservative or expanding?

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have the dynamical systems:

> 1. $dx/dt=y$,
>      $dy/dt=-w^2x$
> 2. $dx/dt=y$,
>      $dy/dt=-by-w^2x$
> 3. $dx/dt=a(y-x)$,
>      $dy/dt=x(b-z)-y$,
>      $dz/dt=xy-cz$
>      with $a,b,c,w\in\mathbb{R}$

How do I determine whether these are dissipative, conservative or expanding? What is the general way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Given the relation 
$$
(\dot{x},\dot{y})=F(x,y)
$$
you can check the [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) of the vector field $F$:
$$
\operatorname{div}F = \nabla\cdot{F}
 = (
\frac{\partial}{\partial x},
\frac{\partial}{\partial y},
)
\cdot (F_1,F_2)
 = \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}
+\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}.
$$

- If $\operatorname{div}F=0$ everywere then the flow is area-preserving,
- if $\operatorname{div}F<0$ everywere then the flow is dissipative,
- if $\operatorname{div}F>0$ everywere then the flow is expanding,
- if $\operatorname{div}F$ changes the sign then the flow has no one of these three properties.